# javascript dynamic css styling

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic

I'm trying to get all characters after "."(dot) and set some styling to them with JavaScript.

Example: $10.12 . I want to set some styling to numbers "12".

I have this number dynamically created in phtml file inside span.

I tried something like this, but without success:

```
var aa = document.getElementById('testdiv').innerHTML; // gets my span
var bb = aa.toString().split(".")[1]; // gets all numbers after "."
bb.setAttribute("style","width: 500px;");
```

Thanks to everyone! You really helped me. I would vote for every answer, but unfortunately I can't vote yet.

Comment: It would help if you posted the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can only apply styling to HTML elements, not text nodes.

Try this instead:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('testdiv');
var parts = elem.innerHTML.toString().split(".");
parts[1] = "<div style=\"width: 500px\">" + parts[1] + "</div>";
elem.innerHTML = parts.join(".");
```

I've used  because it's immediately apparent that a style has been applied, but if you want the number to appear consistent, as in "$10.12" without the "12" on a new line, you will probably need to apply additional styles or rethink how you're outputting the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake begins here:

```
var aa = document.getElementById('testdiv').innerHTML; // gets my span
```

That's not your span, but its HTML contents. To take care of setting the width, you need something like this instead:

```
var aa = document.getElementById('testdiv'); // gets my span
aa.style.width = "500px";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('testdiv').innerHTML = document.getElementById('testdiv').innerHTML.replace( /(\d+).(\d+)/, '$1.<span id="end">$2</span>' );
document.getElementById('end').style.fontWeight  = 'bold';
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4A78R/)**

Your example fails at `bb.setAttribute` since you're trying to set an attribute on a string instead of a node. What you need to do is essentially rebuild the `10.12` with `<span>` elements surrounding the text you want to alter, and then you can use other JavaScript methods to modify the styling. The method you were using was almost correct, except the last part won't work because the `split()` method returns a string, not a node.

Comment: this is what i need, but could you explain this part more specific, please? `( /(\d+).(\d+)/, '$1.<span id="end">$2</span>`

Comment: Sure, that's a regular expression that finds a group of digits, then a period, then another group of digits. When it matches, it surrounds the second group in span tags with an ID of end.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set style to the textNode, the work around is to create an element to wrap the character after "." by using span. The idea is simple. First split it by "." and check if it has "." inside, if yes, create an element to wrap it and set style. Finally, join it back by "."

```
var inner = document.getElementById('testdiv').innerHTML;
var arr = inner.toString().split(".");

if(arr.length > 1)
{
   arr[1] = '<span style="display: inline-block; width: 500px;">' + arr[1] + '</span>';
}
newContent = arr.join(".");
document.getElementById('testdiv').innerHTML = newContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regexp:

```
onlyDigitsText = text.replace(/\.([0-9]*)/g, ".<span class='highlighted'>$1</span>");
```

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ceWdZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var elem = document.getElementById('testdiv');
elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace( /(\d+)\.(\d+)/g, '$1.<span class="decimalPart">$2</span>' );
// (\d+)    one or more digits
// \.       a dot character. Must be escaped otherwise it means ANY character
// (\d+)    one or more digits
// g        regex flag to replace all instances, not just one.
```

Then in your css add styling for the `decimalPart` class

```
.decimalPart {
    width: 500px;
}
```

This has the added advantage of separating your styles from your html.

**UPDATE**

Following your comment to get the character just before the number use

```
 elem.innerHTML.replace( /(\s)([^\s\d]*?)(\d+)\.(\d+)/g, '$1<span class="currencySymbol">$2</span>$3.<span class="decimalPart">$4</span>' );
// (\s)       space, tab, carriage return, new line, vertical tab, form feed
// ([\s\d]*?) any set of characters that are not a digit or the above zero or more times
// (\d+)      one or more digits
// \.         a dot character. Must be escaped otherwise it means ANY character
// (\d+)      one or more digits
// g          regex flag to replace all instances, not just one.
```

Please note I have made an allowance for currency symbols that take up more than a single character.

Comment: Thank you ;) What if I also want to get first element ( not digit ) to add separate style? By first element I mean $ in $12.34.

Comment: Oh and this $ also is dynamical. There can be pounds, dollars and any other values. So I need just the first element. Not '$' element.

Comment: @ArtursNikitins I have amended my answer to include your comments